# JQuery UI dropdown list item limit?

Tags: jquery-ui

Is there a limit to how many items can be populated inside a dropdown list? I am dynamically loading around 500 items to my jQuery UI drop down, it appears to load but if try to select the dropdown to choose a different item, it locks us saying a script on this page is causing the web browser to run slowly.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to rethink your design strategy. Found this for you via Google: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/select-dropdown-with-many-many-options-most-efficient-way-to-populate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these resources:

- [Limit Direct DOM Manipulation](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#limit-dom-manipulation)
- [DOM DocumentFragments](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/)

…and

- [43,439 reasons to use append() correctly](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly)

Remember, if errors like these pop up, it's time to rethink the strategy of how you design your project. This is not premature optimization, because it's the fundament of your app's functionality.

Good luck.